# add new line after every end of file's contents while merging multiple files

Tags: shell-script, xargs, cat

I have written shell script to merge different file's contents I have created directories f1,f2,d1,d2 and files under them , I need to merge all files's contents : comand is

```
(find /home/ah5024331/f1 /home/ah5024331/f2  /home/ah5024331/d1  /home/ah5024331/d2 /home/ah5024331/f1 /home/ah5024331/f2  -type f | xargs -i cat {} ) > t.txt
```

output is :

```
--this is new text from f1 ----
--this is text from f2 ------this is new text from d1 ------this is new text from d2 -----this is new text from f1 ----
```

I need to add new line after every end of file
like:

```
--this is new text from f1 ----
--this is text from f2
------this is new text from d1 
------this is new text from d2 
-----this is new text from f1 ----
```

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: In \*nix each line of a text file shall be terminated by a newline character. If your files were like this then there would be no problem. In fact one of the reasons a newline at the end of the very last line makes sense is the [ability to concatenate easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/10765659) without merging lines. Fix your text files and whatever creates them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find /home/ah5024331/f1 /home/ah5024331/f2 \
    /home/ah5024331/d1 /home/ah5024331/d2 -type f)
do
    cat "$f" >> t.txt
    echo >> t.txt
done
```

This will append a new-line after the end of each file, however, if any of these files already have a new-line at the end, you'll see an extra blank line in the output (as mentioned by @mnmnc in comments).

Comment: Why `echo "FOOBAR" >> t.txt` and not just `echo >> t.txt`?

Comment: Will not work with some files that already have a `\n` at the end. This will create a double new line in some cases. To make it work perfectly you would have to remember last char placed in output and verify on switching to next file i think.

Comment: From what I see she asked: `I need to add new line after every end of file like (...)`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk ops, I misread the question. I'll simplify it as you suggested. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I tried code its not adding new line after every file

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy file with a newline.

```
echo -n "" > /tmp/newline.txt
```

Now execute your script as below.

```
(find /home/ah5024331/f1 /home/ah5024331/f2  /home/ah5024331/d1  /home/ah5024331/d2 /home/ah5024331/f1 /home/ah5024331/f2  -type f | xargs -i cat {} /tmp/newline.txt ) > t.txt
```

Comment: It is not adding new line

Comment: Which Unix OS you are running this script. Remove -n option and try again. Can u paste that output so that we will have some better picture.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
(find ...  -type f | parallel -j1 cat {}';'echo ) > t.txt
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. And it can also replace many `for` loops as in this case.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel